# GAE ValueError with GET parameters

Tags: python, google-app-engine, get

I am trying to create a simple application to return the remainder given two inputs from GET parameters. These inputs will be taken from the url query.

For example http://thisisanexample.appspot.com/?a=1&b=2
This should result in the answer 1 since the remainder of 2/1 = 1.

```
    a = self.request.get('a')
    b = self.request.get('b')
    c = 0
    if (int(a)>int(b)):
        c=int(a)%int(b)
    else:
        c=int(b)%int(a)
    self.response.out.write(type(a))
```

However, I am running into the following ValueError problem: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I am assuming the problem lies in the fact that the variables are previously unknown and may begin as or if not specified, stay as '' thus, creating the error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does `self.response.out.write(type(a))` tell you?

Comment: Not sure about your maths. 2 mod 1 is 0, as 2/1=2 not 1.

Comment: hmmm for some reason it doesn't give me anything. it is responding if i give a super simple command like self.response.out.write(a) which gives me value of a...
and you are right - edited it to the above but still same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GET parameters are stored in request.GET, not in the request itself, so you want to change your code to

```
a = request.GET.get('a')
b = request.GET.get('b')
```

And BTW, where did you write that code? What is `self.request`? If you're writing a view, it shoud be just:

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs ):
    # access request here
```

request.get is not defined on a Django HttpRequest object...

:edit:

GAE is not exactly Django. Citing [GAE's documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestdata.html):

> By default, get() returns the empty string ('')

So your code is correct, but instead of checking whether `a` or `b` are `None`, you should check for empty strings.

Comment: Thanks! I am using coderbuddy and GAE.
Used the following to define self.

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

Comment: GAE is not django, you should change the tags and maybe specify GAE in the question title... See the updated answer

Comment: Actually, using **Class based views**, `self.request` makes sense. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/ (But I'll leave it to you that it's not quite the matter here).

Comment: Agree, but `get` is still not defined on it :-) of curse this is true in Django, while in GAE it works differently, and Sean's code works well

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the GET dict for your query, as the `get` method you are using is a member of the `QueryDict` class. Also, in this case it might be useful to use the default parameter the get method provides:

```
try:
    a = int(self.request.GET.get('a', 0))
    b = int(self.request.GET.get('b', 1))
except TypeError:
    # Could not cast to int
# Do what you want
```

Comment: Ah this is very helpful! Sorry to seem noobish but are the 0 and 1 predefined values?

Comment: Yes, `0` and `1` are the values `a` and `b` will default to if they are not found in the `GET` dict.

Answer (score 1):

If you use get_range (see http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get_range), you can omit the manual conversion to int:

```
self.request.GET.get_range('a')
```